# Ruby zip 3 arrays in two steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following arrays:

```
product_ids = ['id', 'id', 'id'...'id']
product_prices = ['price', 'price', 'price'...'price']
```

on the first step I do the following

```
list_1 = product_ids.zip(product_prices)
```

at this point I have a list with the form

```
list_1 -> [['id', 'price'],['id','price']...]
```

after some calculation I get another array

```
warehouses_stocks = [['stock_1', 'stock_1'..],['stock_2','stock_2'...]]
```

how do I merge this two(list_1 and warehouses_stocks) to obtain another array with the form

```
[['id','price', 'stock_1', 'stock_2'],['id','price', 'stock_1', 'stock_2'],...]
```

Comment: What would be the output if the length of the arrays differ?

Comment: if there is no value for its position would be a blank string "", ['id', 'price', '', 'stock_2'] for example

Comment: Do all the sub-arrays in `warehouses_stocks` contain the same string elements multiple times?

Comment: yes, all the arrays contains the same length, even if is an empty string

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Some feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
product_ids = ['id_1', 'id_2']
product_prices = ['price_1', 'price_2']
warehouses_stocks = [['stock_1', 'stock_1'],['stock_2','stock_2']]
```

`zip` can take more than one argument:

```
product_ids.zip(product_prices, *warehouses_stocks)
#=> [["id_1", "price_1", "stock_1", "stock_2"],
#    ["id_2", "price_2", "stock_1", "stock_2"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the * sign works, I never thought about that.